# cf stop command does not perform graceful shutdown on bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I have a node app in bluemix which holds some transaction cache in memory and I would like to flush this cache to DB before the application goes down. So I have the appropriate event handlers to intercept SIGTERM/SIGINT signals and all works fine from my laptop, however, it seems like the cf stop command does not perform graceful shutdown.

Unfortunately, there is no clear documentation around this topic, at one place in the cloudfoundary app-lifecycle doc they do mention that first SIGTERM is issued and then wait for 10 secs etc but Im not seeing this happening. Probably a bug on their side. https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/app-lifecycle.html

Has anyone noticed this issue and probably have a workaround pls?

Comment: A nice power outage on a host won't be graceful either.  The platform will restart it automatically, somewhere else, without any nice cf stops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CF is sending the SIGTERM first but because of how the app is started by other processes, it's not being correctly propagated to your app.

As a workaround, disable App Management by setting the CF environment variable `BLUEMIX_APP_MGMT_INSTALL=false` and prefix your app's start command in your package.json file with 'exec' (e.g. `exec node app.js`).